# Why does the .NET framework specify standard delegates (Action)?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Why does the .NET framework specify standard delegates? Declaring a new delegate type is simple and can be done in one line of code.

`public delegate void Something<T>(T obj);`

Why do they define all these other types (Action, Action, etc.)?

What is the purpose and what was to be gained by this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Another thing that I wonder about is that they then go on to define 17 versions that are all the same except they take different numbers of type parameters. But why stop at 17? What informs that type of decision?

Comment: So you didn't have to write an extra line of code.

Comment: But that's ridiculous.

Comment: We use Action/Func delegates in our projects.  We don't have a reason to define a specific delegate for use in our application, so the standard Action/Func delegates work for our purpose.  As to what informs that decision, nothing like "that's the max number of arguments".  I think they are just trying to be accomodating.  Honestly if you have that many individual parameters to your method you may have other issues in your code.

Comment: Should everything that uses a lambda declare its own delegate type?

Comment: @PaulDraper Sorry but I don't see how your answers really are in the spirit of the pursuit of knowledge and understanding.

Comment: Hi @Gabe, can you elaborate on that, or post as an answer? That seems legitimate but I am not quite understanding. Maybe an example would help elucidate?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde Take LINQ for example. Would you want to define a delegate for every possible type combination?

Comment: @user2674389 Can you give me an example? Also, the Action delegate only specifies up to 17 type parameters, so it doesn't provide for "every possible type combination"...

Comment: What are the close votes for? They say "primarily based on opinion". I have not expressed an opinion...I have clearly asked a question. Please SO, don't close real questions.

Comment: The close reason means that *answers* will primarily be opinion-based, not necessarily that the question presents itself as opinionated. That being said, it doesn't define an Action for every possible combination because that's just physically impossible, but up to 17 are given to you to cover 99% of your use cases so you don't have to.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the clarification. I think the answer (as given by Sriram and some others) is clearly not a matter of opinion. And it seems that it's not really there to cover 99% of the cases as you suggest. Sriram gives a very good reason for it and I think this is (objectively) *the* answer.

Comment: Spineless Downvoter, announce thyself and intention!

Comment: Your question was answered perfectly by the very first comment by @PaulDraper: the standard definitions save you having to write your own. Your "But that's ridiculous" reply earned you a downvote and an opinion-based vote to close. Any good programmer knows that minimising the number of lines of code one writes is a good thing. So whilst Sriram's answer is good and worthy of an upvote, it's supplementary to Paul's comment.

Comment: @DavidArno I think you are wrong. Paul's answer was not a good one or helpful. Sriram's answer was the correct one. It's unfortunate that you feel the need to police questions and mete out punishments for what you deem to be inappropriate comments, *regardless* of the quality of the question. It's actions like these that are making SO less and less helpful every day.

Comment: @DavidArno Paul's answer is absolutely not correct. Otherwise the .NET framework would be littered with little snippets of meaningless code that would "save us a line" here and there. The correct answer is Sriram's, where clearly without the standard delegate's, implementing Linq and using it would have been VERY clunky.

Comment: I have to say it's hilarious that my "spineless downvoter" dare actually got the downvoter to "announce themselves and their intention! Haha! By the way @DavidArno and PaulDraper, I hope you didn't take anything I said personally. I'm just trying to get my question answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they wanted to expose some delegate definitely for the `TPL` as well as `Linq`, so they created `Action`, `Action<T>` and `Func<>` delegates.

[Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class uses `Func<>` in number of methods.

[Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class was built on top of `Func<>` as well as `Action<>` delegates only.

When they expose the `Linq` in FW it is necessary to declare the delegates like `Predicate` kind of delegate which should operate with `Where` clauses and so forth. You can declare your own delegate in single line. but the point is you can't pass your delegate to framework method, since framework don't have your delegate at compile time.

So framework developers decided to add these standard delegates in the .Net framework itself.

Note:You could pass your own delegates to "BCL" types as `System.Delegate` type and they can use `DynamicInvoke` method to invoke it but that is an overkill. It requires boxing/unboxing when dealing with "ValueTypes" that degrades the performance, not only that `DynamicInvoke` itself poor performing candidate.

Comment: Hi Sriram, would you mind elaborating for me? That seems like the type of answer I am looking for...

Comment: Thanks Sriram. I think this is the answer I was looking for. I will do some more research based on your answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel correct answer. however that would not be boxing/unboxing - boxing/unboxing only happends when casting to/from a value type to reference type

Comment: @markmnl Yep I know that. In my example I mentioned `Where` clause, so it returns `bool` which is a value type. I had that in mind when answering the question. That involves boxing :)

Answer (score 1):

If one piece of code declares:

```
public delegate void SingleArgumentMethod<T>(T obj);
DoSomething(SingleArgumentMethod<int> thingDoDo);
```

and some other code declares:

```
public delegate void OneArgumentMethod<T>(T obj);
PerformAction(OneArgumentMethod<int> theAction);
```

then because `SingleArgumentMethod<int>` and a `OneArgumentMethod<int>` will be unrelated types, there will be no nice way for `DoSomething` to pass its received delegate to `PerformAction`.  Instead it will have to produce an instance of `OneArgumentMethod<int>` using the method pointer(s) and target(s) from `thingToDo`, and pass that to `PerformAction`.  If, however, both methods had used same delegate definition, such complication wouldn't be necessary and `DoSomething` could simply call `PerformAction(thingToDo);`.